# Can't find module that exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, path

From the cli I enter the python shell via `python`.

**I then take a look at my import search path:**

```
import sys
print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/path/to/a/package/foo.bar
/other paths...
```

So I know `foo.bar` is in my python search path.

**Continuing inside the python shell:**

```
import imp
imp.find_module('foo.bar')

ImportError: No module named foo.bar
```

Hmm, the `sys.path` tells me that `foo.bar` is on the python search path, but the `imp` module can't seem to find it.

**Continuing further inside the python shell:**

```
from foo.bar import baz
baz

<module 'foo.bar.baz' from '/path/to/a/package/foo.bar/foo/bar/baz.pyc'>
```

Yes, I have directories `foo` and `bar` under my main directory `foo.bar`. Why would `imp.find_module` not be able to locate my package?

Comment: you say foo.bar is a directory and you try to import it. So python complains stating it's not a module?

Comment: I don't think `foo.bar` is a valid package identifier. `foo.bar` refers to the subpackage `bar` in `foo` (or module).

Comment: @syntonym Even if that's the case, wouldn't `imp.find_module('foo.bar')` give me the location of the subpackage `bar` in `foo` instead of just an error?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel `foo.bar` is a directory and a module. It has an empty `__init__.py` in it. Seems like it should work unless periods in module names don't work with `imp.find_module`.

Comment: @smilebomb I think imp.find_module looks for a module with a name. Because no module can have a name with a dot inside it does not find any. In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html): `This function does not handle hierarchical module names (names containing dots)`

Comment: @syntonym Fantastic, that's what I'm looking for. If you put that in an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imp.find_module` does not handle names with dots. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

> This function does not handle hierarchical module names (names containing dots).

It also points out a solution:

> In order to find P.M, that is, submodule M of package P, use find_module() and load_module() to find and load package P, and then use find_module() with the path argument set to `P.__path__`. When P itself has a dotted name, apply this recipe recursively.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't have a `.` in the folder name.
- Make sure there is an empty `__init__.py` file in the foo & bar folders. This is required for python to see it as a package
- Make sure the folder that the foo folder is in, is in `sys.path`

Comment: The `foo.bar` directory does have an `__init__.py` file. I have already checked the path, that was the first part of my debugging process outlined at the top of my question. Are you saying `imp.find_module` has an issue with periods in the module name?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @smilebomb nvm, syntonym has got the right answer anyways.